# How to get the correct time difference in seconds in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, subprocess, pytz

I am writing a python script to check the time on a remote system using SNMP. I have used the modules subprocess, pytz, datetime and time in this script.

The expected working of this code is, it will get the current time of remote system using subprocess and compare it with the actual time obtained by using the modules pytz, datetime and time. The problem is when I take the time difference using this script, it is not getting me the correct time difference in seconds. Can anyone help me with this?

```
# Finding remote time
snmp_remote_ts = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/snmpwalk", "-r", "3", "-c", "{}".format(snmp_community), "-v", "{}".format(snmp_ver), "{}:{}".format(remote_host,snmp_port), "{}".format(OID_hrSystemDate)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
remote_time = snmp_remote_ts.stdout.decode().split()[-1].replace(","," ").split(".")[0]
remote_ts = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(remote_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()))

# Finding actual time of provided timezone
actual_time_now = int(datetime.datetime.now(timezone(remote_tz)).timestamp())

# Finding time difference
time_diff = actual_time_now - remote_ts
```

The output of snmp_remote_ts will be like this:

```
>>> snmp_remote_ts.stdout.decode()
'HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = STRING: 2022-2-6,13:59:40.0,+5:30\n'
>>>
```

Comment: Is the value in *time_diff* always the same?

Comment: No. If the time in the remote system (timezone: 'Asia/Kolkata') is the same as the actual time (If I give the remote_tz as 'Asia/Kolkata') it will give zero. 
But if I update the remote system time 60 seconds behind the actual time of 'Asia/Kolkata' time zone it is not giving me the time difference in seconds. That's the problem.

Comment: What difference does it give? Are you saying that it stays at zero? If that's the case then your remote server may be using an NTP server to maintain its date/time - meaning that when you set the time it may be overridden by NTP - i.e., self-correcting. Also, the SNMP output looks strange. The time seems to be showing 17hrs (5pm) but that time hasn't yet been reached!

Comment: Actually, this script is a Nagios plugin for monitoring the remote server time using SNMP. My logic is to fetch the time using subprocess from a remote system and compare that time with the actual time. So I am getting the expected result (that is zero) when the remote server time and the actual time of the time zone are same. But, if I edit the remote server time 60 seconds behind the actual timezone time, this script is not giving me the expected result (that is 60 seconds difference) . 

Also sorry for pasting the incorrect SNMP output. I have added the correct output now.

Comment: `time.mktime` only returns correct Unix time if the input timetuple is UTC. Also, since Unix time refers to UTC, comparing that for different time zones makes no sense since the difference is zero by definition.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by rewriting the code as per below:

```
# Finding remote time
snmp_remote_ts = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/snmpwalk", "-r", "3", "-c", "{}".format(snmp_community), "-v", "{}".format(snmp_ver), "{}:{}".format(remote_host,snmp_port), "{}".format(OID_hrSystemDate)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
remote_time = snmp_remote_ts.stdout.decode().split()[-1].replace(","," ").split(".")[0]
remote_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(remote_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Finding actual time of provided timezone
actual_time_now = datetime.datetime.now(timezone(remote_tz)).replace(tzinfo=None,microsecond=0)

# Finding time difference
time_diff = actual_time_now - remote_ts
time_diff_seconds = time_diff.seconds
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: To make sure the result is actually correct an not just *happens to be correct*, why don't you use aware datetime consistently?